# A pointer to field - assignment error/warning

Tags: c

I need to work with 2d field which has always 2 columns. I have a pointer to field for that

```
int (*field)[2];
field = (int (*)[2]) malloc(rows * sizeof(*field)); /*further there will be also reallocating*/
```

The problem comes when I call this pointer to field to a different function. I call this function, but when assigning it to my original field in main, there comes an error/warning. I really tried already so many versions, none of them working.

```
int * function (int rows, int columns, int match, int **differentField) {
    int i, j;
    int (*field)[2];
    int foundMatch = 0;


    field = (int (*)[2]) malloc(rows * sizeof(*field));

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < colms; j++) {
            if (match == differentField[i][j]) {

                field[foundMatch][0] = i;
                field[foundMatch][1] = j;

                                foundMatch ++;
            }

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
       int (*field)[2];
       int rows = 10;
       int columns = 10;
       int match = 1;
       int **differentField;

       /*creating different Field*/

       field = function(rows, columns, match, differentField);


}
```

-> assignment from incompatible pointer type

Any idea how to properly work with this? Thank you really a lot...

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Function `function` is broken in the middle. Post minimally complete code.

Answer (score 0):

You can not return a vector from a function. Instead, you can return a pointer:

```
int ** function (int rows, int columns, int match, int **differentField);
```

This means you declare field as:

```
int **field;
```

Comment: But than you need to allocate each dimension separately. Or is it possible in this way to use in allocation (*)[2] ?

Comment: No, you need to allocate each dimension. Take a look here: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, the compiler is right; a `int *` is not the same as a `int (*)[2]`.  Your code sample is incomplete as it stands right now.  I assume you are intending to return `field` in the `function` function.  However, you have another problem:  You can't return an array.  But, you CAN return a pointer to an array.

If it is field you are trying to return, then the way to declare your return value is:

`int (**function(int rows, int columns, int match, int **differentField))[2]`

Then when you return field, return the address instead (`return &field;`).

Then, in main, `field = *function(rows, columns, match, differentField);`

At least, that should all work.  I think.  It's pretty late and I've been up all night.

At some point you should really look into typedefs to make your life a lot easier.

`typedef int (*field_t)[2];`

Then you can `field_t field;` and `field_t *function(int rows, int columns, int match, int **differentfield);`.  Isn't that a lot nicer?

Comment: Actually you'd have to make `field` in `function` static because you can't reliably return a stack variable address obviously.

Comment: But inside the function `field` is a pointer that points to dynamically allocated memory. Returning `field` would not be returning "a stack variable address". Where do you see a stack variable address being returned?

Comment: `field` itself is a stack variable, and returning the address of it would be a Bad Thing.